# Login form submit button does not work

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I've created a simple one word password login using PHP. The password is stored in the php file - I know this isn't massively secure but all I want is for people to not be able to wander into the site.

For the sake of testing the password is **password**

You can see that I have a jQuery shake effect when it is wrong.

**My Question:**

*Why does my submit button not work with the correct password on hitting the submit button and why does hitting **return** behave differently to the submit button?*

My code:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/vibrate.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body>

      <!-- body content -->
      <div class="wrapper">

          <!-- container -->
          <div class="container">

            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div id="login" class="form-wrapper content-flood">
                    <form action='php/login.php' method="post" class="login-form" id="loginform">
                          <h3 class="text-center">Enter your password:</h3>
                          <input type="password" name="password">
                          <input type="button" name="Submit" id="submit_butt" value="Submit" formaction="php/login.php"/>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>

          </div>
          <!-- end container -->

      </div>
      <!-- end body content -->

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#submit_butt").click( function() {

        // configurations for the buzzing effect. Be careful not to make it too annoying!
        var conf = {
                frequency: 5000,
                spread: 5,
                duration: 600
            };

        /* do your AJAX call and processing here...
            ....
            ....
        */

        // this is the call we make when the AJAX callback function indicates a login failure 
        $("#login").vibrate(conf);

        // let's also display a notification
        if($("#errormsg").text() == "")
            $("#loginform").append('<p id="errormsg">Oops, wrong password!</p>');

        // clear the fields to discourage brute forcing :)

        $("#pwd").val("");
    });

});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
// this password may come from any source.
// it's a variable for the sake of simplicity

$password = 'password';

if($_POST['password'] == $password){
  $_SESSION["userid1"] = $id1;
header("Location: ../home.html"); // redirects
}else{

}
?>
```

Javascript:

```
jQuery.fn.vibrate = function(conf) {
        var config = jQuery.extend({
                speed: 30, 
                duration: 2000, 
                frequency: 10000, 
                spread: 3
        }, conf);

        return this.each(function() {
                var t = jQuery(this);

                var vibrate = function() {
                        var topPos = Math.floor(Math.random() * config.spread) - ((config.spread - 1) / 2);
                        var leftPos = Math.floor(Math.random() * config.spread) - ((config.spread - 1) / 2);
                        var rotate = Math.floor(Math.random() * config.spread - (config.spread - 1) / 2); // cheers to erik@birdy.nu for the rotation-idea
                        t.css({position: 'relative', left: leftPos +'px', top: topPos +'px', WebkitTransform: 'rotate(' +rotate +'deg)', WebkitTransform: 'rotate(0deg)'});
                };

                var doVibration = function () {

                        var vibrationInterval = setInterval(vibrate, config.speed);

                        var stopVibration = function() {
                                clearInterval(vibrationInterval);
                                t.css({position: 'static'});
                        };

                        setTimeout(stopVibration, config.duration);
                };

                /* 
                    Mofication by Kishore - I am commenting out the following line as it calls the vibration function repeatedly.
                    We need to call it only once. So, instead I make a call to doVibration() directly.
                */

                //setInterval(doVibration, config.frequency);
                doVibration();
        });
}
```

;

EDIT: I'm leaving 'else' in the PHP empty becuse the jQuery is handling the error?

I couldn't get a JSFIDDLE of this working but here is the site in action (which is also a test version).

http://hea.getevent.info/

Comment: what do yo mean by submit button does not work and return behaves differently. Could you please explain specific problem?

Comment: Hitting enter with the correct password takes you into the site. Hitting enter with the wrong password shows blank 'login.php'.

Doing the same thing then clicking submit just says oops wrong password

Answer (score 2):

Use input type Submit instead of Button

like

```
   <input type="submit" name="Submit" id="submit_butt" value="Submit" formaction="php/login.php"/>
```

Else you can use input type button and Submit form using AJAX.

Comment: Awesome - this worked however for a second before the site loaded i got the error message :(

Comment: So I changed the input type which made the submit button work correctly with he password and load up the site but while doing that for about a second it shakes and the 'oops, wrong password appears' before entering the site

Comment: Yup exactly :) Works but the error part of the form happens just before entering

Comment: ok wat username and pwd u entered ? so that i can test. after 10 min. u can change password

Comment: It's a test password anyway - typing **password** will work :)

Comment: ok listen firstly, u have <input type="password" name="password"> For password ,So give some id to it . like <input type="password" name="password" id="pwd">

Comment: On Login page u have <script></script> OK ? So, I mean just Replace THis part => `if($("#errormsg").text() == "")` By this  `if($('input[type="password"]').val().length == 0 )`

Comment: @lejimmie , Hi if the answer completes your requirement Then you can Upvote and accept as answer.Anyway I answered what u asked.

Comment: And thanks so much! - still sifting through answers and fixes etc will get back here asap

Answer (score 1):

Instead of attaching the listener to the submit button you should register a listener on the submit action of the form. That way you can capture both the submit button click (once it has changed to a submit button as the other questions have stated) and somebody just hitting enter on their keyboard:

```
$(".login-form").on("submit", function(e)
{

    // Stop the form submitting
    e.preventDefault();

    // Do your checks for errors

    // If there are none

    $(this)[0].submit();

});
```

Comment: I see your logic! So this targets the entire form and not just the submit... Under e.preventDefault(); I write my if { } else { $(this)[0].submit(); }?

Comment: Yes, exactly. That way you capture all submission events of the form as the user might not click the submit button, but hit enter on their keyboard

Answer (score 1):

Your server returns a `HTTP 302` instead of a `HTTP 200`. And I was able to log in, but I did see shaking and an `Oops ...` basically due to poor logic.

```
Remote Address:212.48.79.185:80
Request URL:http://hea.getevent.info/php/login.php
Request Method:POST
Status Code:302 Moved Temporarily
Request Headersview source
```

And your logic does not look quite right, unless I am missing something. We cannot see your ajax but the following statements need to be in the success callback of the ajax call. Both enter and button click worked the same for me. **The code below is fired too early, before your ajax call is complete, AND you also do not prevent default form submission, so it submits too .... twice.**

```
   // this is the call we make when the AJAX callback function indicates a login failure 
    $("#login").vibrate(conf);

    // let's also display a notification
    if($("#errormsg").text() == "")
        $("#loginform").append('<p id="errormsg">Oops, wrong password!</p>');
```

And you need to prevent default so that you can do the submit yourself after you confirm the password:

```
$("#submit_butt").click( function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     .......
});
```

Comment: This is all new to me plus it's bits and bobs put together from various tutorials so yeah definitely bad logic!! :) I will try to implement this and will update how I get on

Comment: You'll get there ... :) My experience has been that I learn quicker by trying ... and the more I try .... the more mistakes I make .... and the more mistakes I make the more I learn. So it's all good; you're on the right track.

Comment: Absolutely, keep practicing until you know it off by heart! Unfortunately, a lot of tutorials these days assume you already have some knowledge, especially of the technical terms :(

I altered the code with your amends and the shaking is much better but the right password is no longer working :(

Comment: BOOM! figured it out!! :) I realized I wasn't doing anything with my code **if the form was correctly filled** so I added (from below) $(this)[0].submit(); - Dunno which answer to mark as correct now :(

EDIT: That didn't work :( made it submit but got rid of the shaking

Comment: Great!! :) Well, use your judgment ... check the one with most value. Just so you know the difference between `$(form).submit()` and `$(form)[0].submit()` ... the former simply triggers the `submit` event while the latter `submits` the form in the default manner ... I did not say it explicitly but I did men the latter. And I may even encourage you to check @alex's answer because he's submitting the form correctly .... using `submit` event on the form rather than a `click` event on a button. **IT'S ALWAYS RECOMMENDED TO LET THE SUBMIT BUTTON DO IT'S WORK ... submit the FORM**.

Answer (score 0):

You're not submitting the form, that's why its not doing the authentication

You could just change your input type from button to  submit:

```
<input type="submit" name="Submit" id="submit_butt" value="Submit" formaction="php/login.php"/>
```

or just submit the form in your click event:

```
$("#submit_butt").click( function() {
  .
  .
  .

  $("#loginform" ).submit();
}
```